# Finding the limit: $\lim\limits_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)}\frac{ 2y\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}{y-3\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I've tried parametric curves using x=at, y=bt, z=ct; I've tried also x=y=z; and z=0, x=y, but in all this cases the limit result zero. I put it on mathematica and the limit doesn't exist (value may depend on x, y, z path in complex space).

I have no idea how to prove that the limit does not exist.

Could you light my path?

Comment: Take $(t,3\sqrt{t^2+t^2}+\epsilon,t)$

Comment: The hint by @Basti reduces the expression to $\frac{12}{\epsilon}t^2+2\sqrt{2}\lvert t\rvert$. So you need something like $\epsilon=t^3$ to demonstrate the limit does not exist. Just letting $\epsilon\to0$ is not enough. It has to approach $0$ significantly faster than $t$.

Comment: May I use this for y? In this case, y is not going to zero when t->0. I couldn't see how $\epsilon=t^{3}$. Sorry.

Comment: if the limit exists, in some neighborhood of $0$ the function must be bound. So, we can pick $t$ small so that $(t,3\sqrt{t^2+t^2}+\epsilon,t)$ is bounded, for all $\epsilon$.

Comment: Ok, so $\epsilon=\epsilon(t)$, and if $\epsilon(t)=t^{3}$, the limit goes to infinity. Thanx a lot to everyone!